# Зачем нужны квадратные скобки у свойств классов и структур

Tags: c#, unity3d

Никак не могу разобраться и найти информацию про скобки `[]`.

```
[SerializeField, Range(1, 15)] private float Radio = 5;
```

Как это работает и что происходит при `Range(1, 15)` ?
Кто-то сталкивался с этим?
Кто-то может дать ссылки или объяснить, как это работает и для чего это нужно?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/

это вам поможет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте про атрибуты в C#.

- В данном случае `SerializeField` помечаются поля которые должны быть доступны в редакторе для настройки (если вы удалите атрибут то в редакторе поле исчезнет, поскольку оно приватное),
- а `Range(1, 15)` устанавливает второй атрибут который показывает что поле должно отрисовываться в редакторе как поле с бегунком и допустимыми значениями от 1 до 15.
  Второй атрибут это из области `PropertyDrawer`, поищите в документации Unity

Answer (score 0):

это артибуты. .NET имеется множество различных классов атрибутов. Например, при сериализации в различные форматы используются атрибуты [Serializable] и [NonSerialized]. С помощью рефлексии стандартные классы .NET получают использованные атрибуты и производят определенные действия. Например, атрибут [Serializable] указывает классу BinaryFormatter, что объекты с данным атрибутом можно сохранять в бинарный файл.

```
public class AgeValidationAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public AgeValidationAttribute()
    { }

    public AgeValidationAttribute(int age)
    {
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

По сути это обычный класс, унаследованный от System.Atribute. Теперь применим его к некоторому классу:

```
[AgeValidation(18)]
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public User(string n, int a)
    {
        Name = n;
        Age = a;
    }
}
```

Пусть некоторый класс User применяет атрибут. Для этого имя атрибута указывается в квадратных скобках. Причем суффикс Attribute указывать необязательно. Обе записи [AgeValidation(18)] и [AgeValidationAttribute(18)] будут равноправны.

Если конструктор атрибута предусматривает использование параметров (public AgeValidationAttribute(int age)), то после имени атрибута мы можем указать значения для параметров конструктора. В данном случае передается значение для параметра age. То есть фактически мы говорим, что в AgeValidationAttribute свойство Age будет иметь значение 18.